# How would plants evolve into motile organisms?

Tags: biology, evolution, flora, futurology

I want to build a speculative future world where the majority of animals on Earth are gone and have been replaced by plants due to convergent evolution. I want to know how these creatures might evolve and adapt to an environment where motility is a necessity and how that world may form.   Here's the list of rules that we begin with:

- The plants are of pure Earth origin: no aliens.
- All vertebrates are extinct, and almost all invertebrates are gone.
- The plants can use an alternate source of power besides the sun, including other 'planimals'.
- The plants must be able to transport themselves around an environment at moderate speed like animals.

Comment: This feels very broad and I'm sure there are very similar questions already asked. Broad as in you could write a book about it! Also, feels like you are more into cresting a discussion whereas wb.se  is an answer to a specific question format.

Comment: Have you looked into the sentient plant questions already asked? I personally asked one about the brain equivalent and I know there were a few more on eyes and muscles and other "body" parts by other users etc!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the [help/on-topic] states, "General guidelines for all questions: Must be specific and answerable: What problem are you trying to solve?" and further the [help/dont-ask] states, "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." A person could literally spend a lifetime writing books about what an evolutionary future can hold.

Comment: it sounds like you already solved this problem is plants have a major source of energy besides the sun.

Comment: Charles Darwin, [*The Movements and Habits of Climbing Plants*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Movements_and_Habits_of_Climbing_Plants) (1865, book published in 1875), and [*The Power of Movement in Plants*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_Movement_in_Plants) (1880).

Answer (score 3):

**Plants are already mobile!**

Check out this video of the parasitic plant called dodder.
https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/624913/view/dodder-parasitic-plant-timelapse

It feels around with its yellow tentacles, looking for prey.  Once it finds the prey plant it drinks its sappy blood.  It is cool because it is parasitic but morning glory vines do the same thing.  https://plantsinmotion.bio.indiana.edu/plantmotion/movements/nastic/twining/vines.html

Vines crawl along seeking the sun, or supports, or prey.  Some epiphytic vines don't have roots - they advance their forward parts by growing them and recycle the hindmost parts as they crawl towards the light.

Maybe you are impatient.  "Too slow!" you bark.  You want a plant that will match you move for move when you fight kung fu and you have been pounding Red Bulls.  That is a big ask for a plant that moves by reallocating water.

But a tumbleweed will take you on!  Plants can definitely move by taking advantage of wind and water and they can move as fast as the wind.  Tumbleweeds tumble to distribute seeds but a plant could definitely blow with wind or flow with water then put down roots again when it came to rest.   If taking advantage of wind to move does not count as moving there are some vultures who want a word with you.  Actually not some; all of them.

---

Ultimately things move because they want resources that are not in their own area.  This is true for plants and animals both.  Plants have mobile components like seeds, or parts like vines or branches or roots.  It would be cool for your future world to riff on the amazing movements plants do now.  Maybe cooler than having a green wolf and saying "It is a plant wolf!  It is green!"